# -bash: create: command not found when 'create' and 'add' on Git

Tags: git, bash

I followed all the instructions for installing git and the command line tools on Mac, but when I try to `$ create` and `$ add files`, `-bash: create: command not found returns`.

I also typed `$ echo ‘export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH’ >> ~/.profile` to add to path, but it still returns command not found.

What would be the reasons for this?

Comment: Please provide the link to see the instructions. I don't know any `create` command for git. Anyway, try opening a new terminal or restart your session to make the changes effective.

Comment: You should in the  root directory of project to `git init`, then you can see the `.git` directory. if the root directory of project have not the `.git` directory means you did not init the git repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`init` and `add` are both **subcommands** of `git`. This means that you must do something like

```
$ git init
```

or

```
$ git add
```

Comment: yup I did $ git init project1, $ cd project1, $ create file1.txt, $ git add file1.txt, but it says command not found when I write $ create and $ add

Comment: `create` and `add` are not commands. You **MUST** use `**git** add` (and `create` is not a git command)

Comment: @Michebae when the instructions say create file.txt they mean to use a text editor to create the file

Answer (score 3):

Are you prefixing correctly the `git` command? Like this:

```
git init
git add
```

Comment: yup I did $ git init project1, $ cd project1, $ create file1.txt, $ git add file1.txt,  but it says command not found when I write $ create and $ add.

Comment: if you're using the postfix alone, as `$ add`, it wont work. Commands git-like need to be prefixed with `git` tool, because `add` its only a subcommands of the tool. Try to see the [manual](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/).

Answer (score -1):

> What would be the reasons for this?
> no reason, i also understood as you
> check this out
> just go to desktop, create a new textfile, name it File1, and cut it to paste it
> at the repository Folder you created by the command $ git init Project1
> you should find a Folder named Project1 at your desktop! haha! or at least at c:users/administrator/Project1 (or any username for the directory)
> paste it there and go back to the Git Bash to continue with
> $ cd Project1
> $ git add File1.txt
> $ git commit. . . . . .etc etc etc
> hope i wasnt LATE!